# Where is extension being set?

Tags: php, apache

I am coding in PHP on Apache, and I have access to two main areas on the Unix server. I have a personal directory and I have a project directory. I noticed that in the project directory there is a extension/module that I have access to automatically which I don't have in my personal directory (I can see it listed in `phpinfo()`).

So I'm guessing that the server admins set it up this way because most users wouldn't require this extension in their personal area, but I do.

I have looked through several base level .htaccess files and conf files, but can't seem to find the point that this extension is being initialized for the project area. Is there a way via PHP for me to list not only all the loaded extensions but at what point they are loaded?

Comment: Are you asking what PHP setting is loading a certain extension and in what file the setting resides?

Comment: Yes. But I'm not asking how to find the `php.ini` file, but where it would be added if it's a `PHP_INI_PERDIR` type extension and has not been set in either the script or the `php.ini` file.

Comment: Where it has been added, sorry. It's definitely somewhere.

Comment: What do you mean with directories? Is your server running 2 different versions of PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of 2 ways for loading extensions

1. through php.ini with the extension/zend_extension directories. Note that this would not work with user.ini files (per directory configuration)
2. through the combined usage of auto_prepend_file INI setting and the dl() function. The latter can load extensions dynamically. And auto_prepend can be used to make the PHP interpreter run any code before yours runs. But dl() has been deprecated in PHP 5.3 and will be completely gone in PHP6.

And if all else fails - why don't you ask your server admins?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way via PHP for me to list
>   not only all the loaded extensions but
>   at what point they are loaded?

No. Ask server admin.